# How do I look at disk journals under OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystems, hfs, journaling, journaled

About 2000 files just turned up missing on my Mac, with no clues as to where they went or how they were deleted.  I have disk journaling enabled, so I'd like to look at the journals.  Hopefully, they'll be able to shed some light on the situation.

How can I look at these journals?  Is there an application or a command-line program?  Are there certain log files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These "Journals" are not actually readable journals as you'd expect. It's a process that is done for you behind the scenes to record changes to files if the disk unexpectedly turns off (power failure for example). Although you cannot read these journals, you can easily repair journaled volumes. You can find further information from these links:

[Mac OS X: About file system journaling](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2355)

[How To Journal a Volume or Repair a Journaled Volume](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21053?viewlocale=en_US)